# Best way to send periodic message to client using sockets

Tags: sockets

There's an application that needs to send messages to a bunch of clients. The clients are applications on users' computers, and those applications sometimes run days at a time. The server either has new instructions, or it doesn't. Sometimes there's 10 minutes between two new instructions, sometimes an hour, sometimes a day. The messages are of fixed length.

What is the best way to implement this? Should I have the clients poll the server every 10 seconds? Should I create a new thread on the server everytime a new client connects, and keep the connection on until there's a new instruction, and then send that to the client and have the client create a new connection?

Or should I push the messages to the clients? I was thinking about how to do that, and I came up with this:
The server server as both a server and a client. When a client handshakes, it gives its address to the server. The server then starts acting as a client(and as a server to enable other clients to connect, obviously), and keeps a connection with the clients. The clients act like servers, and wait for a message.

The last one does seem rather complicated. What is the best way to do this? New messages("instructions") from the server should arrive at the client at least 15 seconds after the server "has" them.

The server-application is going to run on Windows by the way. Of the clients I'm not sure, but let's assume multi-platform. Both the server and the client applications are written in Python.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Perhaps the xmpp protocol can give you some ideas?  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP)

Comment: @thebjorn XMPP seems a bit overkill for what I'm doing, I think. But I've used it in the past for communication over the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have each client open a connection to the server and then wait for any data to be read. The server would write to all the connected clients whenever it has a message to post.

Specifically, the server should `socket()`, `bind()`, `listen()`, and then enter an `accept()` loop. For every new client accepted, it should just add the connected socket to a list of active clients, without reading or writing anything to it yet (except maybe for an initial application-level handshake or authentication, if applicable; in such a case, it should perform the handshake or authentication in a separate thread, in a forked process, or in a non-blocking event loop, to avoid a slow client locking up the other ongoing authentications or even the accept loop.)

The clients should connect to the server (and perform the handshake or authentication if applicable) and then wait for it to have any data for them. The way a client wait on the socket is traditionally done with either `poll()` or `select()`. These calls can be done in a blocking way, in a separate thread or process; or in a non-blocking way, either in the main application loop or triggered by a recurring timer.

Whenever the server has a message to post, it will loop over the list of connected clients, performing a `write()` of the message to each connected client.

The clients will then return from their current or next `poll()` or `select()` with the indication that the socket has readable data and they will proceed to `read()` the message.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But why not use `send()` and `recv()`? `recv()` is a blocking call as well, and the messages have fixed size. Is there any advantage in using `read()` and `write()` instead of `recv()` and `write()`?

Comment: `send()` and `recv()` are used to communicate over UDP, which is a connectionless protocol with no guarantee of delivery. UDP packets may arrive out of order, multiple times, or not at all. In your case I assumed you wanted the client to *know* whether it is still connected to the server or not, so that it *will* receive any messages as soon as they are available. That's what a TCP connection, `read()`, and `write()` are for.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that. I've read up a bit about sockets, but I didn't read about that. The Python Sockets HOWTO doesn't mention anything about that(http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html). What you say is exactly what I want("the client to know whether it is still connected to the server or not, so that it will receive any messages as soon as they are available")

Comment: One more question: how do I remove clients that have disconnected from the list? Should I just add a `try` statement, and remove sockets that throw an exception when trying to write to them? Doesn't seem very elegant, since you can't remove an item from a list while iterating over that list.

Comment: `try` and remove sounds good. In your case you don't need to preserve the order of the items, but you do need to directly address each item to remove it. So you are better off using a `set()` of client sockets. To remove items from a set (or a list, or a dict) being iterated, you can just iterate over a copy: `for x in set(a_set): ... a_set.remove(x)` The added `set()` constructor will make a copy of the collection, allowing you to both iterate and modify it.

Comment: On the other hand, the clients will need a way to be notified as soon as their socket becomes invalid, so that they can discard it and make a new connection to the server. You'll have to experiment to find a way to do so.